# Break up delimted field in access

Tags: ms-access

I have this record in a access table field

93;25;114;734;4019

I need to break it into 5 columns

I have used this to retrieve the first part: Stars1: Left([Stars],InStr([Stars],";")-1)

Please help.

Thanks

Comment: I have used this to retrieve the first part: Stars1: Left([Stars],InStr([Stars],";")-1)

Comment: put that in your question as well

Comment: What does 'delimted' mean?

Answer (score 1):

To use Split() in a query for easily processing your table field "Stars" you could create a new function that takes an additional index parameter and returns a string instead of an Array():

```
Public Function SplitForQuery(s, Delimiter As String, i As Integer)
    Dim x() As String
    If Not IsNull(s) Then
        x = Split(s, Delimiter)
        SplitForQuery = x(i)
    End If
End Function
```

To use that in a query, you would do the following:

```
SELECT SplitForQuery([Stars],";",0) AS Value1,
    SplitForQuery([Stars],";",1) AS Value2, 
    SplitForQuery([Stars],";",2) AS Value3
FROM Table1;
```

You can add as many values as you need, of course and also, if you need to insert your values in another table you can easily transform this query into an INSERT statement.

Answer (score 0):

Use the Split function.

```
Dim rst As DAO.Recordset
Dim strSQL As String
strSQL = "SELECT Stars FROM your_table where ..." ' your where clause
Set rst = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(strSQL)
Dim TestArray() As String = Split(rst!Stars,";") 
'TestArray holds {"93","25","114","734","4019"}
'TestArray(0) holds "93"
```

Comment: Those values are in field in access table called Stars

Comment: Thanks for your see the answer above

Answer (score 0):

Public Function GetFullTextItem( _
  ByVal strFullText As String, _
  ByVal intItem As Integer) As String

On Error Resume Next
  GetFullTextItem = Split(strFullText, ";")(intItem)

End Function

--Star1: GetFullTextItem([Stars],0) etc